# knn- same k, different result

Tags: r, knn

I have a matriz ZZ. After I ran **prcomp** and chose the first 5 PCs I get `data_new`:

```
P= prcomp(zz)
data_new = P$x[,1:5]
```

then I split into training set and test set

```
pca_train = data_new[1:121,]
pca_test = data_new[122:151,]
```

and use KNN:

```
k <- knn(pca_train, pca_test, tempGenre_train[,1], k = 5)
a <- data.frame(k)
res <- length(which(a!=tempGenre_test))
```

Each time I run these 3 last rows, I get a different value in **res**. Why?

Is there a better way to check what is the test error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the documentation of `knn`,

> For each row of the test set, the k nearest (in Euclidean distance) training set vectors are found, and the classification is decided by majority vote, with ties broken at **random**.

If you don't want the randomization to occur, you could use `set.seed` to ensure the same "randomization" on each run.

Comment: Thank you!!! can you please show me how to use `set.seed` and what value should I choose?

Comment: Use `set.seed(x)` where `x` is any number. Different values will yield different randomizations, but using the same value will ensure the same replication.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but you can use `np.random.seed(32)` to fix it.

Comment: This is for Python but the question is in R.