# Why should we use set.seed() before apply knn() in R?

Tags: r, knn

When I read *An Introduction To Statistical Learning*, I am puzzled by the following passage:

> We set a random seed before we apply knn() because if several
> observations are tied as nearest neighbors, then R will randomly break
> the tie. Therefore, a seed must be set in order to ensure
> reproducibility of results.

Could anyone please tell me why is the result of KNN random?

Comment: Because if several observations are tied as nearest neighbors, then R will randomly break the tie. In order to break the tie the same way each time, you set the seed so you can reproduce the results exactly (but your results will then depend on that seed).

Comment: Basically a duplicate of this in reverse: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31750196/knn-same-k-different-result

Comment: Thank you! But I still don't understand why the tie can be broken. Once the training set and testing set are fixed, isn't the neighbor of any point in testing set fixed too?

Comment: If you have three values 1, 2, and 3. How do you group those into two class (k=2). 2 is directly between both 1 and 3.  So which do you assign it to? Well, you need to make a choice so R makes a random choice. Some of the time it groups 2 with 1, other times it groups 2 with 3. Since that process is random, if you want R to make the same choice each time, you need to set the seed to it will make the same "random" choice.

Comment: Thank you. So if I set 'use.all'=T(In the meantime, the training set and testing set are fixed), then even if I don't set seed, the classification will always be the same?

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind that if we use `set.seed()` before `knn()` in R then it helps to select only one random number because if we run `knn()` then random numbers are generated but if we want that the numbers do not change then we can use it.

Comment: I think I understand what you want to say, but it's not very clear how you say it. Can you re-phrase (I changed the grammar a bit).

Comment: Let's me explain. First We use knn() in that algorithm select a random numbers and everytime we run that the random numbers keep change so accuracy can be fluctuated, because of that if we want it does not happen that for we use set.seed().This function help us to set some range of random numbers after use it result can not be change or remain same.