# Why do I get different answers re-running class::knn on the same training and test data?

Tags: r, knn

In the following example, I would expect to get the same results running the knn algorithm on the same training and testing data, but I don't. What's going on?

```r
library(class)
train <- sample(150, 50)
iris_train <- iris[train, 1:4]
iris_test <- iris[-train, 1:4]
y_train <- iris[train, 5]
y_test <- iris[-train, 5]

knn.pred <- knn(iris_train, iris_test, y_train, k = 5)
mean(knn.pred == y_test)
#> [1] 0.91

knn.pred <- knn(iris_train, iris_test, y_train, k = 5)
mean(knn.pred == y_test)
#> [1] 0.92
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: The `knn` algorithm is stochastic. You usually start with a random assignment to groups so your starting condition is different each time you run it. If you need consistent values, you need to set the random seed before running the algorithm: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64674719/why-should-we-use-set-seed-before-apply-knn-in-r

Comment: I'm not sure what a random assignment to groups means in the context of nearest neighbors. Also with `use.all = TRUE`, the default, it seems to me that it should be deterministic.

Comment: Sorry, I was mixing up k-means clustering and knn. But the problem is essentially the same. The algorithm for knn also uses randomness to break ties (as described in the link I provided). You can go through the code if you want to see exactly where. But if you set the random seed to a specific before calling the function, you'll set the same result.

Comment: Thanks. According to the documentation `use.all` "controls handling of ties. If true, all distances equal to the kth largest are included. If false, a random selection of distances equal to the kth is chosen to use exactly k neighbours." So I'm not sure why I'm getting different results even with `use.all = TRUE`. I will check the code.

Comment: Looking more carefully at the docs I see that there can be ties in which points are chosen to be nearest neighbors AND/OR the majority vote for class among the nearest neighbors. `use.all` seems to only control the former.